# Screen goes black occasionally except for windows

Tags: 20.04, gnome, themes, window

GNOME occasionally goes completely black except for the windows currently open. This happens every ~20 minutes, and is pretty annoying. After a few seconds, the screen reverts back to normal. I can't take a screenshot because I can't see the app menu...

Example: I have Chrome and Terminal open. When this happens, I cannot see the background picture, the top panel, or the taskbar. I can only see Chrome and Terminal.

Ubuntu 20.04 LTS; Orchis theme, Sweet Dark v40 applications, BeautyLine icons; custom 5.13.15 kernel.  X window system.

MacBook Pro 16,1 - i7-9750H, AMD Radeon Pro 5300M. Samsung 21:9 Ultrawide 40" monitor.

Comment: Can you boot into a live session to see if you get the same issue? If so that would tell you it’s almost certainly a hardware issue.

Comment: Very likely this is related with all that customization.